# MSCV, constructor, destructor and NRVO behaviour

Tags: c++, c++11

I was wondering if the [NRVO](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slippman/archive/2004/02/03/66739.aspx) was active on the project I was working on (which is Qt, using MSVC 2013 64 bit).

So I wrote this piece of code:

```
class foo
{
public:
    foo(){qDebug() << "foo::foo";}
    foo(const foo& c){(void)c;qDebug() << "foo::foo( const foo& )\n";}
    ~foo(){qDebug() << "foo::~foo";}
};
foo             bar()
{
    foo local_foo;
    return (local_foo);
}
void                    func()
{
    foo f = bar();
}
```

and it gave me the following output:

> foo::foo
>
> foo::~foo

Where the link I put above expects :

> foo::foo()
>
> foo::foo( const foo& )
>
> foo::~foo()
>
> foo::~foo()

But when I replace the bar call by

```
foo f = foo(bar())
```

then I get the same output that the links has.

So here's my question: why does "foo f = bar()" not call copy constructor? does it call the operator= instead, and before it is call, f is raw storage? (So why the link, which is from 2004, doesn't behave the same way)?
So I must conclude NRVO isn't turned on, right?

Comment: Surely your conclusion is backwards?

Comment: Why couldn't you run both the optimized and unoptimized version of the code and compare the output from both?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie What do you mean the "optimized" and "unoptimized" version?

Comment: @Krapow Ah, now we get to the crux of the problem.  An unoptimized version does not turn on NRVO - what you see is what you get.  In other words, a "Debug" build is by default, unoptimized.  A "Release" build is optimized.  You could have simply turned off optimizations, build and run the program, get the results.  Then turn on optimizations, build, run, check the results.  Then conclude from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why does "foo f = bar()" not call copy constructor?

Because the compiler is allowed to [elide](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) the copy.

> does it call the operator= instead, and before it is call, f is raw storage?

No.

> So why the link, which is from 2004, doesn't behave the same way

Presumably they used another compiler, another version of the compiler or other settings for the compiler and their compiler did not elide the copy.

> So I must conclude NRVO isn't turned on, right?

From the first input you can conclude that NRVO **is** turned on. From the second output you can conclude that there was one copy that was not elided. But, since there are less copies printed than would be if there was no NRVO, you can conclude that NRVO is turned on, but not applied to all copies.

> what is the difference between "foo f = bar()" and foo f = foo(bar())" then?

The first copy-initializes `f` from the return value of `bar()`

The second constructs a temporary object using the copy constructor explicitly and then copy-initializes `f` from that temporary object. Both of the copies can be elided.

Comment: Clear answer.
A little side question: what is the difference between "foo f = bar()" and foo f = foo(bar)" then?

Comment: @Krapow I updated my answer with that question but I fixed the missing parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is allowed to elide copies.  It can determine that the local `foo` is going to go out of scope so instead of creating the `foo` in `bar` and then copy it can construct the object directly into `f`.

> So I must conclude NRVO isn't turned on, right?

No.  This means it is turned on.

```
foo f = foo(bar())
```

Should have the same effect on any decent optimizing compiler.  running

```
class foo
{
public:
    foo(){std::cout << "foo::foo\n";}
    foo(const foo& ){std:: cout << "foo::foo( const foo& )\n";}
    ~foo(){std::cout << "foo::~foo\n";}
};

foo bar()
{
    foo local_foo;
    return (local_foo);
}

int main()
{
    foo a = bar();
    foo b = foo(bar());
}
```

<kbd>[On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/054ebe4a0d6cb7dc)</kbd>

We get

```
foo::foo
foo::foo
foo::~foo
foo::~foo
```

Which shows that both copies can be optimized away into a single construction.

Comment: When i run your code, I got 6 prints, not the 4 you got. I don't think our compiler behaves the same way.

Comment: @Krapow No it is not.  For some reason your version of MSVS is not optimizing the second condition.  Did you compile in debug or release build?

Comment: I use release mode on Qt Creator. I checked the Makefile, no debug flags are on.

Comment: @Krapow So what is the `/O` parameter set for?  That is the optimization flag for the Visual C++ compiler.  That is the first thing you should have mentioned, even going back to your original post.

Comment: -02 is present in the Makefile's CFLAGS variable.

Comment: @Krapow It looks like it is an issue with MSVS.  Even 2015 does not optimize the double copy into a single construction like g++ and clang do.

Comment: Thanks you all for your answer, time and help, I got all I needed  :)